# Using Source Maps with Mocha JS in Browser

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Is it possible when using Mocha JS as the test runner in the browser, to have it use generated source maps?  I'm migrating a project to use webpack and the compiled output is obviously not useable for debugging.

Note: I'm not using Mocha from the command line, so the option `--enable-source-maps` is not available, as far as I can tell? Attempting to pass in the key to `mocha.setup()` just breaks the test suite.